Keras multi-label model predictions always sum to ~1
I believe I've configured this model correctly for multi-label classification, but it would seem that it insists on behaving like a multi-class model, since the predictions it outputs always sum to 1 (e.g. [0.2, 0.8]).
First my dataset config, the label_mode gives me the one-hot encoded inputs I should need for multi-label:
train_dataset = utils.text_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    seed=seed,
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical')

val_dataset = utils.text_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='validation',
    seed=seed,
    label_mode='categorical')

My TextVectorization layer shouldn't be relevant to the problem but I'm including it anyway just in case I'm missing something here:
def standardize(input):
    input = tf.strings.lower(input)
    input = tf.strings.regex_replace(input, r'[^a-z ]', '')
    return input


encoder = layers.TextVectorization(standardize=standardize)
encoder.adapt(train_dataset.map(lambda text, label: text))

And finally the model:
model = keras.Sequential([
    encoder,
    keras.layers.Embedding(
        input_dim=len(encoder.get_vocabulary()),
        output_dim=50,
        # Use masking to handle the variable sequence lengths
        mask_zero=True),
    keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(50)),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
                metrics=[keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])

history = model.fit(
    train_dataset, epochs=4,
    validation_data=val_dataset
)

I've tried binary, categorical, and F1 metrics, the results are the same regardless.
A prediction like this will invariably be two values whose sum is between 1.02 and 0.98, regardless of the contents of input_string.
tensor = keras.ops.convert_to_tensor(np.array([input_string]))
print(model.predict(tensor, verbose=0)[0])

Any help would be appreciated!

Is it possible that my training dataset doesn't have sufficient variety? All of my training data is of one class or the other, like a multi-class problem might be, do I need to include some data that's of more than one label, or no label, to get the network to not behave like a multi-class categorization?

It seems like you build a binary classification model. What makes you think that you constructed a multi-label classification model?

I’ve one-hot encoded the labels, and I’ve tried categorical accuracy functions, which don’t seem to change the output. I’ve been training it on two labels at the moment, but I want it to recognize data that doesn’t fit either one also, would I need to train the model on data that doesn’t fit either label with a one-hot vector [0, 0] to achieve that?

I think you're probably right, that when the training data always has $y_1+y_2=1$, that the model will tend to settle on a solution with $\hat{y}_1+\hat{y}_2\approx1$. Including examples with neither or both labels should change that. A more thorough justification for that first sentence, with a specific loss function on the NN, would make a good answer IMO. I'm not so familiar with keras to say for sure it's behaving as you expect though.
